# Laravel multiple where clause checking for null values through a variable

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am storing a where clause in a variable

```
if($condition === 1) {
    $whereClause = ['mID' => NULL, 'qid' => $listing->lID, 'deleted' => false];
}
else {
    $whereClause= ['mID' => $member->mID, 'qid' => $listing->lID, 'deleted' => false];
}
```

And I get the collection via

```
$collection = Model::where($whereClause)
```

BUT on the first condition, I actually want the `mID` to be either 0 or NULL, I want to retrieve items where mID can be 0 or NULL, so I want orWhere clause, which I did use as shown below, but this does not work, gives an error of memory exhausted so something went wrong

```
if($condition === 1) {
    $whereClause = ['mID' => NULL, 'qid' => $listing->lID, 'deleted' => false];
    $orWhereClause = ['mID' => 0, 'qid' => $listing->lID, 'deleted' => false];

     $collection = Model::where($whereClause)->orWhere($orWhereClause)

}
else {
    $whereClause= ['mID' => $member->mID, 'qid' => $listing->lID, 'deleted' => false];
    $collection = Model::where($whereClause)

}
```

Any ideas of how I can achieve this sort of where condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like the easiest method. Chaining `where()` methods is the same as passing them in as an array.

```
$collection = Model::where('qid', $listing->lID)->where('deleted', false);

if($condition === 1) {
    $collection = $collection->whereIn('mID', [0, NULL]);
}
else {
    $collection = $collection->where('mID', $member->mID);
}
```

(Note that [according to the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses), if you wanted to pass an array to the `where()` method, you were doing it wrong.)

Answer (score 2):

Except for the missing of ";", i think that you should implement it in this way:

```php
$whereClause = [['mID', NULL], ['qid' , $listing->lID] , ['deleted', false]];
$orWhereClause = [['mID', 0], ['qid' , $listing->lID] , ['deleted', false]];
$collection = Model::where($whereClause)->orWhere($orWhereClause);
```

and if you need other condition, just push an array in the right array where the first parameter is the field and the second the value, or first parameter is the field, the second the operator and the third the value

Comment: This will include any records that have `mID = 0` regardless of whether `deleted = false` or `qid = $linting->lID`.

Comment: @miken32 edited, please try and tell me what happens

Comment: amazing! workwell. thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Miken32 is correct, but the code could be written in a single query instead of adding the `where()` in an if/else statement:

```
$collection = Model::where('qid', $listing->lID)->where('deleted', false)
->when($condition === 1, function($q){
    $q->whereIn('mID', [0, NULL]);
})->when($condition !== 1, function($q){
    $q->where('mID', $member->mID);
});
```